# VueJS & DataTables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables

I am learning vue.js and i have some struggle in showing data in datatables. I am sending request to get data from server via Fetch API, datatables is seeing it but not showing in table version.

```
<DataTable :options="options" width="100%" :columns="columns" :data="getData" class="aside-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="aside-column">ID</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">NAME</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">MUSIC</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">TOTAL VIEWS</th>
                                <th class="aside-column uppercase">from swipe
                                </th>
                                <th class="aside-column">FROM TRENDS</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">FROM CATEGORY</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">VIDEO START</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">COMPILE BTN CLICK</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">COMPILE</th>
                                <th class="aside-column uppercase">save camera roll</th>
                                <th class="aside-column uppercase">show subs on save
                                </th>
                                <th class="aside-column uppercase">subscription</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">LIKES</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">SHARES</th>
                                <th class="aside-column">VIDEO CANCELLED</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </DataTable>
```

Here is the HTML template which contains only

Table contains columns which is already shown in , data and options which are basically necessary

```
const dataItems = async () => {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${myToken}`,
            'Content-Language': 'en',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

    const all = {
        id: 0,
        template_name: "All",
        music_title: "All",
        views_count: 0,
        transitions_from_trends: 0,
        transitions_from_category: 0,
        compile_count: 0,
        compile_btn_click_count: 0,
        video_start_count: 0,
        video_cancelled_count: 0,
        like_count: 0,
        share_count: 0,
        transitions_from_swipe: 0,
        save_camera_roll_count: 0,
        show_subs_on_save_count: 0,
        subscription_count: 0
    }

    await apiDataFetch(`/admin/statistics/template?type=${type}`, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            let array = response.data
            array.forEach(item => {
                all.views_count += item.views_count
                all.transitions_from_trends += item.transitions_from_trends
                all.transitions_from_category += item.transitions_from_category
                all.compile_count += item.compile_count
                all.compile_btn_click_count += item.compile_btn_click_count
                all.video_start_count += item.video_start_count
                all.video_cancelled_count += item.video_cancelled_count
                all.like_count += item.like_count
                all.share_count += item.share_count
                all.transitions_from_swipe += item.transitions_from_swipe
                all.save_camera_roll_count += item.save_camera_roll_count
                all.show_subs_on_save_count += item.show_subs_on_save_count
                all.subscription_count += item.subscription_count

                items.push(item)
            })

            items.unshift(all)
        })

    console.log(items)
}

const getData = computed(() => {
    dataItems()
    return items
})
```

Here is my Javascript block which contains function which recieves data from server and puts into array in order to show it.

I can not find the problem which is stopping the dataTables give me the result into table

Comment: Is `<DataTable>` a custom component or from a library? It'd help to include library information or include code showing how DataTable uses its `data` prop.  Also, it is considered a very bad practice to introduce side effects inside computed properties. It makes the code not predictable and hard to understand. If your fetch should be done in response to something changing, consider using a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html), otherwise just call `dataItems()` on created/mounted lifecycle hook.